# Returning datasets from LINQ to SQL in a REST/WCF service

Tags: wcf, linq

I have a WCF/REST web service that I'm considering using Linq to SQL to return database info from.

It's easy enough to do basic queries against tables and return rows, for example:

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
    public List<User> GetUsers()
    {
        List<User> ret = new List<User>(); ;
        using (MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext())
        {
            var userResults = from u in context.Users select u;
            ret = userResults.ToList<User>();
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

But what if I want to return data from multiple tables or that doesn't exactly match the schema of the table? I can't figure out how to return the results from this query, for example:

```
 var userResults = from u in context.Users
   select new  { u.userID, u.userName, u.userType, 
                 u.Person.personFirstname, u.Person.personLastname };
```

Obviously the resulting rowset doesn't adhere to the "User" schema, so I can't just convert to a list of User objects.

I tried making a new entity in my object model that related to the result set, but it doesn't want to do the conversion.

What am I missing?

Edit: related question: what about results returned from stored procedures? Same issue, what's the best way to package them up for returning via the service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a [Complex Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472.aspx) and instead of returning Anonymous object you return the Complex Type. When you map stored procedures using function import, you have a option to automatically create a complex type.

Create a custom class with the properties that you need:

```
public class MyTimesheet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then create it from your Linq query:

```
using (linkDataContext link = new linkDataContext())
{
    var data = (from t in link.TimesheetDetails
               select new MyTimesheet
               {
                   Id = t.Id,
                   Data = t.EmployeeId.ToString()
               }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: That's the Entity Framework, not straight Linq To SQL. I'm trying to avoid using the Entity Framework if at all possible.

Comment: Oh I see. You can create a concrete class instead of an anonymous one just like m4tt1mus suggested.

Comment: BUT... let's say I do use Entity Framework. I know how the complex types work with stored procs, that's not an issue. How does one map the linq to sql query I have above to the complex type? Nothing I'm trying is working.

Comment: I tried that - I get an exception "The entity or complex type 'MyModel.MyResult' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query"

Comment: It seems to work just fine for me. Can you describe the 'MyModel.MyResult' class? Is it a table in you DB by any chance?

Comment: No, it's a complex type I created using the model browser. Basically right-click on "complex type", add a new complex type, and add in scalar properties that match my query. I'm basically trying to avoid hand-coding classes if possible (maybe it's not...)

Comment: Perhaps you can post more uptodate examples in your original question?

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't return domain objects from a service because if you do you'll run into issues like those you're finding. Domain objects are intended to describe a particular entity in the problem domain, and will often not fit nicely with providing a particular set of data to return from a service call.

You're best off decoupling your domain entities from the service by creating [data transfer objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) to represent them which contain only the information you need to transfer. The DTOs would have constructors which take domain object(s) and copy whatever property values are needed (you'll also need a parameterless constructor so they can be serialized), or you can use an object-object mapper like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org). They'll also have service-specific features like [IExtensibleDataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iextensibledataobject.aspx) and [DataMemberAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347792.aspx) which aren't appropriate for domain objects. This frees your domain objects to vary independently of objects you send from the service.