# Clean way to deal with circular references in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, circular-dependency

Say I have this table structure:

```
Client
-----------
ClientId                     int            not null    (identity)
CurrentDemographicId         int            null        (FK to ClientDemographic)
OtherClientFields            varchar(100)   null


ClientDemographic
------------------
ClientDemographicId          int            not null    (identity)
ClientId                     int            not null    (FK to Client)
OtherClientDemographicFields varchar(100)   null
```

The idea is that Client (in EF) will have a ClientDemographics list and a CurrentDemographic property.

The problem is when I setup the object structure and try to save it, I get this error:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values

This error makes sense.  I have a circular reference in my table setup.  It does not know which entity to insert first (because it needs the Id from both tables at the same time).

So, I hacked together a solution that looks like this:

```
// Save off the unchanged ClientDemograpic
ClientDemographic originalClientDemographic = client.CurrentClientDemographic;

// Merge the contract into the client object
Mapper.Map(contract, client);

// If this is a new client then add as new to the list.
if (client.ClientId == 0)
{
    dataAccess.Add(client);
}

// Restore the original ClientDemographic so that EF will not choke
// on the circular reference.
ClientDemographic newClientDemographic = null;
if (client.CurrentClientDemographic != originalClientDemographic)
{
    newCurrentClientDemographic = client.CurrentClientDemographic;
    client.CurrentClientDemographic = originalClientDemographic;
}

// save our changes to the db.
dataAccess.SaveChanges();

// Restore updates to ClientDemographics and save (if needed)
if (newClientDemographic != null)
{
    client.CurrentClientDemographic = newCurrentClientDemographic;
    dataAccess.SaveChanges();
}
```

But changing the reference back to the previous value, saving, then setting it again so I can save again feels like a hack.

Is there a cleaner way to deal with circular references in EF?

Answer (score 17):

I'd say the answer is: "not really". The only clean way to deal with the circular reference is to look again at the design and remove it.

In this case - approaching it from a Domain Driven Design perspective - I'd say that `Client` is the root of your aggregate and `ClientDemographic` is a value object; `ClientDemographics` are defined by the values of their 'Other ClientDemographic fields'. You can therefore remove `ClientId` from `ClientDemographic`, and the problem is prevented instead of cured.

That said, if you're settled on this structure then unfortunately I don't think there's a neat way of handling it in EF, no.

**Edit**: To give `Client` multiple `ClientDemographics` as well as a `CurrentClientDemographic` property, you can go the other way; remove `CurrentClientDemographicId` from `Client`, and add an `IsCurrent` binary field to `ClientDemographic`. The EF then gives you a `ClientDemographics` collection property, and you can add the following yourself in a new, partial class:

```
public partial class Client
{
    public ClientDemographic CurrentDemogaphic
    {
        get { return ClientDemographics.First(cd => cd.IsCurrent); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmmmm, I would like to change the design, but a Client can have more than one demographic in the database.  Even though Client is the root, I sometimes need all the ClientDemographics for a client (and sometimes just need the current one).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your effort to find a solution for me.  Unfortunately I have other dependencies that don't allow me to take this solution.  The short of it is that I am using WCF Data Services (OData) to publish my data.  WCF Data Servcies can only publish what is actually in the EF Model.  Partial classes and such things are not published.  (A significant missing feature in my opinion, but the benefits of OData outweigh this problem.)

Comment: You're welcome :) As I mentioned in an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834085/returning-datasets-from-linq-to-sql-in-a-rest-wcf-service/6834897#6834897), I'd recommend not mixing domain model objects with WCF. Instead, I'd create a separate layer of Data Transfer Objects tailored specifically for your WCF needs, and map between them and your EF objects. Your DTOs can have circular dependencies, and the EF won't need to know about it :)

Answer (score 3):

The simple way of avoiding this error is to create your primary object first, SaveChanges and then create your dependant object before calling SaveChanges again.

In this case create the Client first, SaveChanges, then create the ClientDemographic object, add it to the collection and set it as the CurrentDemographic and then SaveChanges again.

Comment: This is not a neat solution. `SaveChanges()` in UoW issues a Commit for database transaction. And after the first `SaveChanges()`, any failure in performing the second one may break the database consistency, or at least the domain logic consistency.

Comment: This is not a neat solution, but as mentioned above, there is no neat solution. Your choices are to use my method and deal with rollback manually or else change your model.

Comment: @MassoodKhaari Surely a transaction can help conserve database consistency in case of failure during `SaveChanges`?

Comment: @ProfK @Nathan Phillips One duty of Unit of Work pattern, upon which EF DbContext is based, is to ensure that all the data changes within it are either committed or discarded altogether. In case of the failure of `SaveChanges`, none of the changes are committed to DB and thus the DB consistency is not endangered.

It is not wise to break a business transaction into two separate UoWs (two `SaveChanges`), because you may have half the transaction saved, which may cause business loss and require manual corrections.

Comment: @MassoodKhaari I agree with what you are saying, but if the database is not yours to change, and you still wan't to either commit or rollback, I suggest wrapping the linking and multiple calls to save changes in a transaction scope.