# more than one navigation to the same entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have a problem with connection between 2 entities when there is 2 navigations.

to be specific, I have the following classes:

```
public class TableA
{
    public TableA()
    {
        ListBs = new List<TableB>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public TableB MainB { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TableB> ListBs { get; set; }
}

public class TableB
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual TableA refA { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }

}
```

The scenario of this particular classes reflects the following:
TableA has a list of TableB objects
and also has 1 main TableB object(that is of course in the list too).
Also a TableB object may not actualy have a reference to TableA

the fetching works.
but when I try to insert new items I get the following exception:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

Any idea where I got anything wrong?

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100568/clean-way-to-deal-with-circular-references-in-ef

Comment: the problem is not a circular reference.  After a lot of fiddling and trying I narrowed it to inserting a new object(with no id) to both navigation properties.

Comment: I use breeze and the only work around solution I could find on this issue was to save the entity twice: first add reverenced entity to the list and save. Then set it as the extra referenced item and save again.

Answer (score 0):

use this Code :

```
public class TableA
{
    public TableA()
    {
        ListBs = new List<TableB>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int TableB_Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("TableA_Mains")]
    [ForeignKey("TableB_Id")]
    public TableB MainB { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("refA")]
    public virtual ICollection<TableB> ListBs { get; set; }
}

public class TableB
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int TableA_Id { get; set; }

    [Foreignkey("TableA_Id")]
    [InverseProperty("ListBs")]
    public virtual TableA refA { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }


    [InverseProperty("MainB")]
    public virtual ICollection<TableA> TableA_Mains { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of [InverseProperty("TableA_Main")] ?

Comment: Should it somehow reference the constructor of TableA? Did you test your code? Is there some documentation for such kind of inverseproperty references? I could not get it working. Please also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943464/how-to-specify-two-navigation-relations-for-ef-breeze-unable-to-determine-a-va

Comment: Ah, now I see. TableA_Mains is the name of the collection in TableB. Sorry and thank you for the other example as well.